# How to access representation of the hidden layers in CNTK 2.2?

Tags: hidden, cntk, representation

Assume I have a simple model.

```
def create_model(out_classes):
    f1 = Dense(16, activation=C.relu,bias=True,init_bias=0,name='FLayer')
    l1 = Dense(16, activation=C.relu, bias=True, init_bias=0, name='LLayer')(f1)
    c1 = Dense(out_classes,name='CLayer')(l1)
    return c1

model = create_model(nClasses)
z = model(feature)
```

How do I access the representation of the FLayer or LLayer during the testing of my trained model?

Answer (score 1):

By representation you mean accessing the functions of the hidden layers correct? I created a sample code to show it. I tested two approaches, the first one builds on what you did and the second one uses the functional API of CNTK which I prefer.

The easy way to get access to the functions is to return them:

```
import cntk
import numpy as np


def create_model(output_dimension):
    l0 = cntk.layers.Dense(shape=1, activation=None, init=1, init_bias=1)
    l1 = cntk.layers.Dense(shape=output_dimension, activation=None, init=1, init_bias=1)(l0)
    l2 = cntk.layers.Dense(shape=output_dimension, activation=None, init=1, init_bias=1)(l1)
    return l0, l1, l2

input_dim = 1
output_dim = 1
l0, l1, l2 = create_model(output_dim)
input = cntk.input_variable(shape=1)
layer0 = l0(input)
layer1 = l1(input)
layer2 = l2(input)

print("Non functional API")
print("output of layer 0: {}".format(layer0.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
print("output of layer 1: {}".format(layer1.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
print("output of model: {}".format(layer2.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
```

The above model takes an input of dimension 1 and output a vector of dimension 1. I also set the weights and biases to 1 in each layer so it is easy to follow the computation. The function create_model returns a tuple which contains all the layers so these can be accessed externally.

The functional API approach is better in my opinion. Below, I create a list containing the different layers and then I build the model using `cntk.layers.Sequential`. Then, `create_model2` returns a tuple whose entries are 1) the list containing all the layers and 2) the final model. This is cleaner when you have several layers. Also, it gives you better control with regards to what you can do with each layer.

```
def create_model2(output_dimension):
    layers = [cntk.layers.Dense(shape=1, activation=None, init=1, init_bias=1),
              cntk.layers.Dense(shape=output_dimension, activation=None, init=1, init_bias=1),
              cntk.layers.Dense(shape=output_dimension, activation=None, init=1, init_bias=1)]
    m = cntk.layers.Sequential(layers)

    return m, layers

m, layers = create_model2(output_dim)
layer0 = layers[0](input)
layer1 = layers[1](input)
layer2 = layers[2](input)
layer01 = cntk.layers.Sequential(layers[0:2])(input)
layer012 = cntk.layers.Sequential(layers[0:3])(input)
model = m(input)

print("Functional API")
print("output of layer 0: {}".format(layer0.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
print("output of layer 1: {}".format(layer1.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
print("output of layer 2: {}".format(layer2.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
print("output of model: {}".format(model.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
print("output of layer 0 and 1: {}".format(layer01.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
print("output of layer 0 and 1 and 2: {}".format(layer012.eval({input: np.array([0], dtype=np.float32)})))
```